# Subject or Object Pronoun

Tags: grammar

In the sentence below, is the pronoun "I" used correctly?

"If you mean that letter, then it was I who tricked you."

Comment: Yes, 'I' is formally correct. In informal contexts it's OK to use 'me'.

Comment: ...Though 'It was me who ...' sounds far worse than 'It was me.'.